# TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of null Angular2 Router

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, router, angular2-router3

Below is my component. Point of error is the `this.router.navigate()` part. After login, I wanna redirect the user to a different page, something similar to `$state.go('dashboard')`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/auth/login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) { }
  onSubmit(formData) {
    if(formData.valid) {
      console.log(formData.value);
      this.af.auth.login({
        email: formData.value.email,
        password: formData.value.password
      }).then(function(success) {
        console.log(success);
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And I keep getting this error. Please enlighten me, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use `Arrow function` instead of `function` inside `.then`'s `success` & `catch` callback's. Due to which inside `success` & `catch` callback `function` you're loosing component `this`(context).

**Code**

```
this.af.auth.login({
   email: formData.value.email,
   password: formData.value.password
}).then(
   //used Arrow function here
   (success)=> {
      console.log(success);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
   }
).catch(
   //used Arrow function here
   (err)=> {
      console.log(err);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
   }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate straightforward simple answers. Got it working now. I need to familiarize myself more with Typescript or es6 whatever these things are

Comment: Instead of using arrow functions can you pass scope to to another function? Like in this situation, passing scope to this.handleError: .catch(this.handleError)?

Comment: No.. then this.router will be unreachable.. we have to either use `arrow function` or `.bind(this)`

Comment: Aha.. never do that. Use arrow functions